# Let's Encrypt in Dokku in Docker - docker.env: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, ssl, lets-encrypt, dokku

When I try to enable letsencrypt it can't find `docker.env` file although it exists, I checked manually. Here is the error log.

```bash
ubuntu@arm1:~$ dokku letsencrypt:enable nextjs-app
=====> Enabling letsencrypt for nextjs-app
-----> Enabling ACME proxy for nextjs-app...
       ok: run: nginx: (pid 18034) 3421s
-----> Getting letsencrypt certificate for nextjs-app via HTTP-01
        - Domain 'nextjs-app.dokku.arm1.localhost3002.live'
docker: open /home/ubuntu/traefik-proxy/apps/dokku/dokku-data/home/dokku/nextjs-app/letsencrypt/certs/ac00fb3b1783f8750bfd5ca350e514d4918ca459/docker.env: no such file or directory.
See 'docker run --help'.
-----> Certificate retrieval failed!
-----> Disabling ACME proxy for nextjs-app...
       ok: run: nginx: (pid 18034) 3421s
 !     Failed to setup letsencrypt
 !     Check log output for further information on failure
```

It's an empty file but it exists, here it is from the container:

```bash
ubuntu@arm1:~/traefik-proxy$ docker exec -it dokku bash
root@2c3660d832dd:/tmp# cat /home/dokku/nextjs-app/letsencrypt/certs/ac00fb3b1783f8750bfd5ca350e514d4918ca459/docker.env
root@2c3660d832dd:/tmp# ls -la /home/dokku/nextjs-app/letsencrypt/certs/ac00fb3b1783f8750bfd5ca350e514d4918ca459/docker.env
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dokku dokku 0 Feb 25 17:20 /home/dokku/nextjs-app/letsencrypt/certs/ac00fb3b1783f8750bfd5ca350e514d4918ca459/docker.env
```

And here it is from the host:

```bash
ubuntu@arm1:~/traefik-proxy$ ls -la /home/ubuntu/traefik-proxy/apps/dokku/dokku-data/home/dokku/nextjs-app/letsencrypt/certs/ac00fb3b1783f8750bfd5ca350e514d4918ca459/docker.env
-rwxr-xr-x 1 200 200 0 Feb 25 17:20 /home/ubuntu/traefik-proxy/apps/dokku/dokku-data/home/dokku/nextjs-app/letsencrypt/certs/ac00fb3b1783f8750bfd5ca350e514d4918ca459/docker.env

sudo vi /home/dokku/nextjs-app/letsencrypt/certs/ac00fb3b1783f8750bfd5ca350e514d4918ca459/docker.env
```

I use this `docker-compose.yml`:

https://github.com/nemanjam/traefik-proxy/blob/main/apps/dokku/docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  dokku:
    container_name: dokku
    # image: dokku/dokku:0.30.1
    build:
      context: .
      # install pack in Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3022:22'
    environment:
      - DOKKU_HOSTNAME=dokku.${SERVER_HOSTNAME}
      - DOKKU_HOST_ROOT=${PWD}/dokku-data/home/dokku
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/dokku-data:/mnt/dokku
      - ${PWD}/plugin-list:/mnt/dokku/plugin-list
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proxy
```

**dokku report nextjs-app:** https://gist.github.com/nemanjam/1e66aa8683ea3535fe1a1ea1848f1dab

**dokku ps:inspect nextjs-app:** https://gist.github.com/nemanjam/629767d02b5493b8eeb42ee9171d8f55

**`~/traefik-proxy/apps/dokku$ tree -da .`:** https://gist.github.com/nemanjam/6437f96ed522fb812e45ea5231ebe05a

Comment: You may have messed up your volume bind mount locations, or there could be a permissions issue preventing reading. It's not at all clear what paths you're trying to mount from your question.

Comment: @AndyRay i just used local `./dokku-data` instead of `/var/lib/dokku` so it's easier to reset Dokku install. Relative positions are preserved and absolute position shouldnt matter, here guy from Dokku also mounted to local folder:

https://github.com/dokku/dokku/discussions/5522#discussioncomment-4413356

Comment: @AndyRay you can see all app and container settings on links i posted in gists on the bottom of my post.